# jqGrid navButtonAdd not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a `jqGrid` in my project and I would like to add custom buttons, but no button appears in the grid and as far as I see there is no syntax problem. I have tried to simplify my grid, but the button still did not appear. I use `Velocity` template engine, that's why I have the `$` symbol in my code, that does not refer to jQuery.
I am using jqGrid 3.8.2.

Here is how I construct the grid:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

                function loadCompleteHandler(){
                    jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid('setGridHeight', Math.min(500,parseInt(jQuery(".ui-jqgrid-btable").css('height'))));
                }

                function select1() {
                    return ": ;false:no;true:yes";
                }

                function select2(){
                            return ": ; 1:Select1;2:Select2;3:Select3";
                }

        var colModelData = [
                    {name:'1', index:'1',width:'5%', hidden: true, align:'center', sortable: false, resizable:false},
                    {name:'2', index:'2',width:'10%', align:'center', formatter: 'checkbox', sortable: false, editable: true, stype: 'select', edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: {value: "Yes:No"}, searchoptions: { value: select1()}, resizable:false},
                    {name:'3', index:'3', width:'35%', sortable: false, resizable:false, defaultValue: ''},
                    {name:'4', index:'4', width:'30%', sortable: false, resizable:false, defaultValue: ''},
                    {name:'5', index:'5', width:'20%', sortable: false, defaultValue: '$selectedValue', stype: 'select', searchoptions: {value: select2()}, resizable:false},
                    ]

        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid({
            url: '$urlManager.getURL("/myPath/My.json")' + '?param1=param1Value&param2=param2Value',
            datatype: 'json',
            postData: {
                filters: '{"groupOp":"AND","rules":' + 
                         '[{"field":"field3","op":"eq","data":"$selectedValue"}]}'
            },
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames:['', '<input type="checkbox" id="selectionCheckbox" onclick="checkboxClick(this)">', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5'],
            colModel : colModelData,
            width:'768',
            height: 500,
            pager: '#pagerDiv',
            gridview: true,
            rowNum: 50,
            rowTotal: 500,
            sortorder: 'desc',
            onSelectRow: function(id){
                    if (id){
                        if (id !== lastSel) {
                            jQuery('#listTable').restoreRow(lastSel);
                            jQuery('#listTable').editRow(id, true);
                            lastSel=id;
                        } else {
                            jQuery('#listTable').editRow(id, true);
                        }
                    }
                },        
            editurl: '$urlManager.getURL("myPath/MyScreen.vm")',
            caption: 'Caption',
            hidegrid: false,
            viewrecords: true,
            loadComplete: loadCompleteHandler,
            ignoreCase: true,
            search: true,
            page: $page
        });

            jQuery(function(){
                jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{
                                    stringResult: true,
                                    searchOnEnter: false });
            });


            jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pagerDiv",{edit:false,add:false,del:false})
                                .jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pagerDiv', {caption: "Edit",
                                    onClickButton:function(){
                                        console.log('Button clicked');
                                    }});
    <script type="text/javascript">

    <table id = "listTable"> </table>
    <div id = "pagerDiv"></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code has some problems. The main error is that you miss `});` at the end of your JavaScript code. Another problem that you use `jQuery(function(){...` inside of `jQuery(function(){...` which make the code bad readable. I suggest you additionally to reduce the number of *global* functions. In your current code the functions `loadCompleteHandler`, `select1` and `select2` are defined on the top level and are global. You should better place the code inside of any function (like inside of `jQuery(function(){...});`). More better is to define inline functions. Next remarks: you should always use radix parameter (10 in your case) in `parseInt` function and don't include trailing commas (see `},]` at the and of definition of `colModelData`).

One more variable: `lastSel` should be defined. The `$page` are also unclear for me. In my modification of your code which you will find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Atticus2.htm) I just replaced it to 1. In any way you can see in the demo that `navButtonAdd` method work fine in the modified code.

I recommend you to use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) which can help you to improve the quality of your code.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. You are right about the syntax errors, I have made some mistakes when I have copied and rewritten the code. The main error was the missing '});' as you have mentioned. Thanks again!

Comment: @Atticus: You are welcome! I recommend you to use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/). If you cut&paste the JavaScript code from my demo in JSLint you will have no errors. If you don't like restrictions used by JSLint you can add many options in the comment at the beginning of the JavaScript code. JSLint can improve the quality of your code. Many other developers (like developers of jQuery) use JSLint permanently.

Comment: I have one more question if you are still following this thread. Why is it important to include every jqGrid definition in a 'jQuery(function(){ });'? I see that the previous solution would work if I included it in a separate 'jQuery(function(){ });'.